# Share BIN folder for multiple web application on Azure App Service (or IIS)

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

It's possible to share same bin folder for different web application (.net 4.6) on Azure App service (it is possible also on IIS)

I'd like to have on bin folder, and for each web application have different web.config like showed below

```
root
|
|  BIN (share *.dll)
|
|- App1
|--  web.config
|
|- App2
|-- web.config
|
|- App3
|-- web.config
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of a good way to do this.  This question has come up a couple times before if you search for it.  You could maybe use NTFS junctions, but that seems like a terrible idea.   If you haven't considered the GAC, that's how you do stuff like this, but I assume you've already considered that.

Comment: No. Unless you invent your own "ASP.NET", it only works the Microsoft way. The philosophy behind is that each application is the smallest unit of deployment, so they should have their own bin folders.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it, but you may be able to do something like this with the new Bring Your Own Storage feature in preview by mounting the blob storage as the relelvant folder. It doesn't work with standard App Services right now though. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/bring-your-own-storage-to-app-service-on-linux/